# Not regexp_like, find null values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

Doing data checking of input data in staging tables prior to loading into the main system tables.  Because I want to use the same field checking in Apex I have implemented the checks as regular expressions using 'not regexp_like' to return any field that does not match its pattern.  However, for a mandatory 10 character field I expected a pattern such as:

'^.{1,10}$'

to return any field that was null with the fields that were too long, it does not, null fields are not returned.

Is there a regexp pattern that will do this?

Example:

```
    select col
                from (select null col from dual
                            union all
                            select 'A string' from dual)
            where not regexp_like(col, '^.{1,10}$')
```

Removing the 'not' returns 1 row as expected...

The point here is to force the pattern to find the null, not to use regexp_like to find the good values and then exclude them, or to use an NVL on the field.  This checking is already expensive enough!

I am assuming, that like most Oracle code involving null what is happening here is that regexp_like sees null and therefore returns null?

Does Java script and Java behave in the same way?

Thanks

Bob

Comment: This is a consequence of how NULLs are handled in relational databases in general. You should see exactly the same behavior in any relational DB. As to how Javascript and Java behave - these are not relational databases and do not follow the same rules.

Comment: Hi Bob - Does this mean that Java and Java script will generate errors for zero length in the above?  Again, I have assumed yes, and assume is always dangerous...

Comment: Java and Javascript are not relational databases. They don't have the concept of NULL in the same manner as does a relational DB. As to the question of "will they return errors for zero length" I have no idea - why don't you test it and find out?

Comment: LOL, next step... That project just got low priority against other pressing issues...

Answer (score 6):

Oracle has 3 states in the result of a boolean expression: `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL` (unknown).

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( NULL, '.' )
```

Will return `NULL` and not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Negating the expression to:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE( NULL, '.' )
```

Will also return `NULL` and not `TRUE` or `FALSE` and, since it is not `TRUE` then the row will never be returned.

Instead you need to explicitly check for a `NULL` value:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE( col, '^.{1,10}$' )
OR    col IS NULL
```

or, more simply:

```
WHERE LENGTH( col ) > 10
OR    col IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I was coming to the conclusion that it would need a 'not null' in there, disappointing, I wanted to use pattern matching throughout.  Using length is possible, it is what is currently done, but by using the regular expression so many other things can also be checked at the same time where data have specific formats.  And then, with a web page the patterns can be loaded and used as pattern string validation as the user enters data.   I was hoping this would give me a very precise bullet to clear many checks in one hit!

Comment: In this situation I was hoping that the pattern was everything...  To keep it  that way I have to parse the pattern to see if it is nullable, then add the not null.  The simpler solution is to add a 'not null' column to the table holding the patterns, but then I have an extra column not tied to the pattern... Not what I wanted!

Comment: But is does confirm that in Oracle, NULL is always UNKNOWN, and will therefore always return UNKNOWN, ie NULL, in any normal operation upon it...  Normal Operation - one that does not include specific null operators, NVL, NVL2, is null etc, although decode seems to deal with it!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to get the strings with zero or more than 10 characters, you can simply use:

```
length(col) > 10 or col is null
```

About `NULL`, the only check you can rely on is `is [not] null`.

For example:

```
select length(null) from dual
```

gives `NULL`, not `0`.